# issue with Looping through lists to write new rows in a csv file using python

Tags: python, loops, csv, file

I am trying to add content to my existing csv file. meaning I would not like to remove any existing content but just like to add new lines based on list of lists.

However, in the final output I don't see any new row being added in the csv. Also the variable is returning empty list values (please see the comment on the code line).

Here i am asking the user first the number of entries. then value for each entry (each row value for each column). Then I am simple appending it to a final list i.e total_number_of_rows which should look like:
[[x,x,x][xy,xy,xy].

In the final code I am trying to write the values from the two lists to the CSV file for example the final output should look like:

```
id, name, color
oldvalue1, oldvalue2, oldvalues3  #assuming this is an already existing row in the csv file
x,x,x
xy,xy,xy


number_of_entries = int(input("how many entries will you need to enter:"))
each_new_row = []
total_number_of_rows = []
for i in range(number_of_entries):
    new_id = input("add new new_id")
    new_name = input ("add new date")
    new_color = input ("add new color")
    each_new_row.extend((new_id,new_name,new_color))
    print("each_new_row",each_new_row)
    total_number_of_rows.append(each_new_row)
    print("total number of rows", total_number_of_rows) # this is showing [[1,1,red],[2,2,blue]]
    each_new_row.clear()
print("total_number_of_rows", total_number_of_rows) ## this is showing [[],[]]


  
with open('file.csv', 'a',newline ="") as f:
      
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(total_number_of_rows)
    #not seeing any new row added
```

Comment: i am populating the total_number_of_rows with values using the list method. somehow that is not going through. Even if i add print("total_number_of_rows", total_number_of_rows) right after each_new_row.clear() i.e directly below it, it shows the same results

Comment: `# this is showing [[1,1,red],[2,2,blue]]` that's not true, you should check that again. Maybe you will notice what the problem is then.

Comment: it's something with the `each_new_row.clear()` that's causing the issue.  If you comment that out both `total_number_of_rows` print statments work correctly, but then your lists aren't separated correctly into sublists

Comment: It may show `[[1,1,red]]` or `[[2,2,blue], [2,2,blue]]`, but not `[[1,1,red], [2,2,blue]]`.

Comment: @JD2775 exactly i tried to remove it, can you suggest how can i solve that issue ?

Comment: @trillion I think you should first figure out why your append is not working the way it should be.  The resulting list is only showing the last set of values entered, X number of entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> each_new_row = []
> # ...
> for i in range(number_of_entries):
>     # ...
>     total_number_of_rows.append(each_new_row)
>     # ...
>     each_new_row.clear()
> ```

This appends the *same* list multiple times to `total_number_of_rows`. At the end you clear this list, and that's why `total_number_of_rows` contains only empty lists (it's the same empty list multiple times).

Instead, you want to create a *new* empty list in every iteration instead of reusing the same list over and over.

```
for i in range(number_of_entries):
    each_new_row = []      # do this
    # ...
    total_number_of_rows.append(each_new_row)
    # ...
    #each_new_row.clear()  # don't do this
```